# Grabbing div content and sending to php email

Tags: php, email, html

New here and glad to be, I've gotten a lot of answers from this forum. I am however stuck at the moment.

I have some javascript that is creating a window color and handle picker (click on the color swatch it changes the image, click on a handle and it does the same). Below the image is a description of the window selected. This text is being generated by the javascript by pulling the image titles.

Now the fun part. Below this picker I need to add a form that will be emailed using php. Within that email I need to pull the window description that is being generated by the javascript.

I have tried so many things today I have lost count. The last bit of code I tried was

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("windowDesc").each(function() {
       var html = jQuery(this).html();
   });

});
</script>
```

And in the php mail file I added:

```
$windowtitle = $_GET['html'];
```

as well as trying

```
$windowtitle = $_POST['html'];
```

and I have also tried the following:

```
<script>
    var content = $('#windowDesc').html();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'send_mail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                    content: content
            }
    });
</script>
```

And in the php mail file I added:

```
$windowtitle = $_GET['content'];
```

as well as trying

```
$windowtitle = $_POST['content'];
```

Not to mention a plethora of other things.

Basically what I am trying to do is grab the content of the div that holds the generated text and email it. If any of the above are correct then I must be placing them in the wrong position or something. With the first one I have tried it inside the form, outside the form, before the div, after the div. Just haven't tried it on top of my head yet. It's been a long day, thanks in advance :o)

Sorry for the delay, been a busy two days. OK, so here is the code that handles the window color and handle picker:

```
var Color = "color";
var Handle = "handledescription";
var ColorDesc = "color";
var HandleDesc = "handle description"
function Window(Color,Handle,ColorDesc,HandleDesc) {
    $('#windowPic').animate({opacity: 0}, 250, function () {
        thePicSrc = "http://www.site.com/images/windows/" + Color + Handle + ".jpg";
        $('#windowPic').attr('src', thePicSrc);
        $('#windowDesc').html("<p>" + ColorDesc + " frame with " + HandleDesc + " hardware</p>");
        $('#windowPic').animate({opacity: 1}, 250)
    })
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wColors li').click( function() {
        Color = $(this).attr('id');
        ColorDesc = $(this).attr('title');
        Window(Color,Handle,ColorDesc,HandleDesc);
    });
    $('#wHandles li').click( function() {
        Handle = $(this).attr('id');
        HandleDesc = $(this).attr('title');
        Window(Color,Handle,ColorDesc,HandleDesc);
    });
});
```

Comment: The Javascript using `$.ajax` looks about right, and the PHP with `$_POST` is correct. However, you need to put the Javascript into an event handler function, so that it runs when you do something that triggers it. If you put it at the top level of your script like that, it just runs once when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am rather new to javascript/ajax, could you please explain further in relation to putting it into an event handler function.

Comment: Something like the click handler for a submit button, or the completion function of your color picker. You have to run the AJAX code after something happens to change the color.

Comment: Sorry, still pretty much lost. I understand what you are saying, but not sure what the code would need change to in order to add the event handler. It would obviously need to be a function whereby when a person clicks on a colour swatch the new text is picked up.

Comment: Without seeing the code that implements the color picker, I don't know where you should put it. So I'm just describing it in generic terms. Check the API for the color picker to see if it takes a callback function to be invoked after the user has selected something.

Comment: Ah good point. So next question, which is not coding or script related, where on earth can I add the script? Can't add it to a comment and it gave me an error when trying to transfer it to chat.

Comment: Click the "Edit" link under your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a hidden input in your form:

```
<form id="send_email" action="send_email.php">
  <input id="content" type="hidden" name="content"/>
  ... other inputs here
</form>
```

Then you can use Javascript to fill it in before submission:

```
$("#send_email").submit(function() {
    $("#content").val($("#windowDesc").html());
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you so much. As a note in case it helps someone else, just had to put a ); at the end of the js :o) Thanks Barmar, you are a star.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var content = $('#windowDesc').html();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'send_mail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: content
    });
</script>
```

It worked here.